# Squid proxy server giving the error 'The system returned: (110) Connection timed out'

Tags: proxy, squid

I get the error "The system returned: (110) Connection timed out" from the browser when I try to browse through the squid proxy server....Any suggested solutions???

Comment: Try a `squid -Z`

Comment: Tried it,not working..I get a "1445942383.529  60082 x.x.x.x TCP_MISS/503 0 GET www.google.bf:443 ######### HIER_NONE/- -" in my access.log

Comment: can you give me your squid config `/etc/squid3/squid.conf` and post the output of  `sudo service squid3 status`

Comment: @Neil the config is quite long.....Too long to be posted

Comment: @quadriola copy it to  pastebin and link it here

Comment: @ Neil http://pastebin.ca/3223641

Comment: @quadriola line 20 `acl Localnet src x.x.x.x/16` should be something like `acl Localnet src 192.168.1.1/16`

Comment: Yeah...x.x.x.x/16 represents an IP address..

Comment: The problem I had was that the squid proxy had a parent proxy ...So i added the line "cache_peer Y.Y.Y.Y parent ##  no-query default login=username:password never_direct allow all"....where Y.Y.Y.Y is the parent proxy ip and ### is the port....

Answer (score 0):

You try to connect [www.google.bf](http://www.google.bf:443/) on port 443 and the return code is 503, means *Service Unavailable*

> 503
>
> The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance). Generally, this is a temporary state.

[image]